# Is it good design to have state-representative properties on a service class?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I have an application with a service class that retrieves database metadata from a database and returns it to calling classes.

To connect to the database, the service class methods accept a parameter that details the connection credentials.

I'm considering a change whereby the credentials would be stored within the service class. One of the reasons for this is that calling classes (which have the responsibility, for example, of comparing schemas on different servers) may connect to multiple different databases/servers, so the calling class would basically have a collection of these service classes, rather than a collection of connection credentials (e.g., `IConnectionInfo` in the following example).

Another thing I might like to do within the application is to have implementation of this service class (`IDatabaseService` in the following example) for different types of RDBMS (e.g., SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), and this seems like the best way of leaving it open to that (the information returned from the service would be very generic and applicable to all supported types of RDBMS).

Example code for what the service class might look like:

```
public class DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
{
    private readonly IConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo;
    
    public bool IsConnected; // INotifyPropertyChanged
    
    public string ServerName => IConnectionInfo.ServerName;
    public string DatabaseName => IConnectionInfo.DatabaseName;
    
    public DatabaseService(IConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<Table> GetTables()
    {
        ...
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<Column> GetTableColumns(Table table)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

There are a few reasons I'm a bit doubtful of this approach:

1. I'm implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` within this class so that I can update the UI to show the user whether or not they are connected (e.g., I could switch this to false if any calls to the server failed). For this reason it seems to behave like a ViewModel (as opposed to a Service).
2. I'm unsure as to whether it's good practice to have properties on a service class that represent its state, e.g., `ConnectionInfo`, `IsConnected`.

Does the above look like an acceptable design?

**Update: Further Thoughts and Explanation**

I suppose the specific programming problem I'm trying to solve is that, for example, I might have a class for SQL Server credentials, and a class for Oracle credentials, both of which would be `IConnectionCredentials`. I would then have several corresponding implementations of `IDataService`, which would accept `IConnectionCredentials` as an argument. The issue would be that not all implementations of `IDataService` would work with all implementations of `IConnectionCredentials`, which seems flawed to me, and so I thought it would make sense to combine the data access layer and the "data accessor" object into one class. I suppose it might be feasible to have `IDataService` contain logic to determine which version of the "real" data access interface to use. For example:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private readonly RealDataServiceFactory RealDataServiceFactory;
    
    public IEnumerable<Table> GetTables(IConnectionCredentials connectionCredentials)
    {
        return RealDataServiceFactory.Create(connectionCredentials).GetTables(connectionCredentials);
    }
}

public class RealDataServiceFactory
{
    public IRealDataService Create(IConnectionCredentials connectionCredentials)
    {
        if (connectionCredentials is SqlServerConnectionCredentials)
        {
            return new SqlServerDataService();
        }
        else if ...
    }
}
```

Another reason I wanted the `IsConnected` property in the data access class is because there are other reasons that the service might not return data other than the connection not working, and I didn't feel the logic to determine that belonged in the calling class, and so liked the idea that the data service could simultaneously return null to some call and also state to the application and UI, "there's a problem with my connection". In the above implementation, I would also lose this, though I suppose it could be achieved by the data service marking `IsConnected` as `false` on the incoming `IConnectionCredentials` before returning.

Comment: The `DatabaseService` in itself is just a Model. Whether you expose it to the view with `INotifyPropertyChanged` properties doesn't affect an MVVM design. IMHO MVVM is just a way to do a "Separation of Concerns" which used to be called Three Tiered Archtecture...its just a new name on an old design pattern.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Thanks - to give a little more information about what the class will be doing, it might, for example, have a method that uses a `SqlConnection` to connect to a database and retrieve data, etc. - would it still be classed as simply a Model?

Comment: You have *business logic* on a model (and an instance) which handles the connection, *which has `SqlConnection` operations/instance*. That main instance would reside on the VM and the view will bind to that instance's properties to show status. How the *levers* of connection are pulled, up to you. But I have **done** what you propose as similar design for the past 20 years. MVVM purists may complain but as long as you don't have a SQL injection scenario on this class exposed to the View, that is what matters and this class (model) can be reused elswhere. That's my opinion, I could be wrong.

Comment: The Spiffing Brit would call it "Fair and Balanced". :-)

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Thanks again, it definitely makes sense to me. As a final question: While reflecting on this I remembered I have a method on the current `DatabaseService` that accepts two `ConnectionInfo` parameters so it can do a comparison. With this new type of design, would it therefore make sense/be acceptable to have a method on `DatabaseService` that accepts another `DatabaseService` as parameter?

Comment: So in a sense, you are overloading the constructor of the class; unless I am missing something, seems fine.

Comment: Not overloading the constructor, it would just be a single method on `DatabaseConnection` with a signature such as `bool TablesAreTheSame(DatabaseConnection otherDatabase, string tableSchema, string tableName)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's ultimately up to you what to do, but it sounds like this design conflates two (or more?) concerns into one:

- User interface updates (`INotifyPropertyChanged`)
- Data access

This gives the class more than a single reason to change. In other words, it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) (SRP).

Now, no-one says that you *must* obey the SRP. This, and the other [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), are guidelines for dealing with certain kinds complexity. If you don't have the problems that SOLID addresses, then you don't have to follow those principles.

In practice, though, it can be hard to predict future problems. A code base is rarely problematic from the outset. It slowly devolves from something simple to something more complicated.

While the proposed design sounds like it has mixed concerns (as opposed to separation of concerns), perhaps it's benign in practice. After all, `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a base class library interface, so you're aren't introducing coupling to some specific technology. I'd be wary of expanding the scope of UI-related updated on that class, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does sum up what I've been thinking. While I doubt I would ever expand on the UI-related elements of the class, it still doesn't sit quite right with me. I've updated my question with some further information that explains more specifically the programming problem I'm trying to solve.